# I want to ask about the Google document protocol-buffers encoding

Tags: protocol-buffers

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?hl=eng#structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNWKf.png)

I understand why drop msb from "value".

However, I don't know why msb is dropped on the "key" side.

? 000 1000: key

1 001 0110: value (msb: 1)

0 000 0001: value (msb: 0 = end)

"key" has a byte after it, so the number to enter msb is 1 (1 000 1000)

or

I think there is no reason to drop msb because "key" is 1 byte.(0000 1000)

but It dropped msb and msb bit is 0.

Why is the value 0 even though it dropped msb?

Answer (score 0):

You need to think of the key, in isolation, as an integer, and varint encode that integer *by itself* using varint encoding. The integer shown (b1000) only needs 4 bits, so in varint encoding that is a single byte with a 0 MSB. But keys can be much much larger. Think of field number 1708 - the *number* (not including the wire type) is b11010101100 - so that's 11 bits for the number, plus 3 bits for the wire type, so we have 14 bits of data to encode. Varint is a 7-bit encoding, so we can store that in 2 bytes: the first will have the MSB 1, and the second will have the MSB 0.

Or in other words: any MSB when discussing the key is there to help you find *where the key stops being encoded*. It has nothing to do with the payload that comes afterwards.